# Apply patch file Magento 2.2

Tags: patches

After downloading a patch via curl to my install directory, I tried installing it with `patch -p0 < CE-MAGETWO-93036.patch` but could not find the file to be patched.
The patch file specifies `diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php b/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php` but my standard 2.2 install does not include these a and b directories. Naturally it failed to change the file and patch asked me to specify the file to be changed and I entered `vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php` and that worked fine.
Question: Why do the patch files specify these a and b directories, and is there a better way to apply patches?

Thanks